# Lexicographic Order of Expression [Automata Theory]

Tags: automata, regular-expressions, kleene-star

what will be kleene star "expansion" of expression $a^*b^*$ in lexicographic order?
I'm confused and I really want to clear my concepts so I can proceed further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lexicographic order is defined on words, not on regular expressions. An interesting exercise is to describe the restriction of the lexicographic order to the language $a^*b^*$, assuming that $a < b$. Note for instance that
$1 < a < a^2 < \dotsm < a^n < \dotsm$, but $\dotsm <a^nb <\dotsm <a^2b < ab < b$.

Comment: I want an example question regarding this if you can provide me with that

Comment: What do you mean by an "example question"?

Comment: My bad wrong post I had multiple tabs open and posted this comment here instead of the other one